# How can I configure how the header of an alert dialog

Tags: android

Is there a way to configure how the header of an alert dialog looks?
It nows has an icon (on the left) with text as title. Is there a way to add view on the same line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't add an additional view to the title.  However, you can use a custom title with `AlertDialog.Builder.setCustomTitle(View)`.  If you just wanted to replace the icon or text, you could use `setIcon()` or `setTitle()`, respectively.